# Image's GPS information not available when user clicks a pic to upload

Tags: javascript, gps, exif

I am building a web app where a user can upload an image and from there we get the location of the image by reading the exif data of the same, for achieving the same, I am using [this](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) library which is working fine, however when in phone if a user choose the option to use the camera for uploading the pic after clicking it, then we are not receiving the GEO meta data for the image. My file field is as below.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Check the raw file from the mobile - does it contain the geo meta data?

Comment: The image that I click to upload directly is not getting saved to the Gallery